# D: (ddbc) can I do SELECT with one request?

Tags: sql, d

I am using https://github.com/buggins/ddbc

Example it's explicitly show how to do SELECT request:

```
auto rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, name name_alias, comment, ts FROM ddbct1 ORDER BY id");
while (rs.next())
    writeln(to!string(rs.getLong(1)) ~ "\t" ~ rs.getString(2) ~ "\t" ~ strNull(rs.getString(3)));
```

But can I do it's in shorter form? For example without while. Does this request can be written in another form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your definition of "one request" is. The select statement is only executed one time, rs then provides a pointer into the results which is possibly several requests to the SQL server (but I don't think it would always be).

It looks like the library provides a way to use a structure to describe the data layout, in which case you could obtain all data in one line (after defining the struct):

```
auto users = stmt.select!User.array
```

Comment: something like string [] foo = stmt("SELECT * FROM ...")

Comment: Could you provide any simple example, to better understand how to use it. Is "select!" is template?

Comment: @Suliman, I don't have this library setup to run my own tests, I'm having to go off the documentation that exists. I believe this is the code for select used above: https://github.com/buggins/ddbc/blob/master/source/ddbc/pods.d#L799